# Center a table in a word document using interop.word in C#

Tags: c#

I've been using interop.word in C# and I want to center a table in a document, all the rows are centered but I need the whole table to be centered in my document. I just can't find the property to center the whole table in a document. I've already centered all the rows but I need the table to appear centered in my document.

Answer (score 10):

did you try `table.Rows.Alignment = Word.WdRowAlignment.wdAlignRowCenter` ?